# Can I use the same Eclipse workspace simultaneously on two computers?

Tags: eclipse

My friend and I need to use the same Eclipse workspace. I've put it on an AFP server, so we can both mount the volume and use the workspace there. But will that work without problems as long as we are not editing the same file at once? For example, if there are classes Starter and View, could I be editing Starter.java and saving the project while he edits and saves View.java?

I know that Eclipse cannot normally use workspaces on AFP due to a bug. I had to add "-Dosgi.locking=java.io" to the eclipse.ini file to make it work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use source code management system?

Comment: I think it is easier to share an Eclipse and Java installation, so that you can both access the same features and API's. Then you simply use a default configuration and configure as much as possible within the project. This gets saved in the `.project` and `.classpath` files in the root of the project. These files you can share using your favorite source control system. You may use AFP for the Eclipse install & API, but it may be better to `rsync` those files to a local folder instead.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen I tried GitHub, and it is definitely not easier. If this fails, I can use Dropbox I guess.

Comment: Maven might also be of interest here I think... What about using subversion as source code management system or even using CVS with the already build in CVS client for Eclipse?

Comment: @owlstead We have the same Eclipse installation separately on each computer. Do you mean that we should run the Eclipse app itself from the same location?

Comment: As soon as you find the changes you make affecting the changes your partner makes, I can guarantee that version control will be simpler than what you're proposing here.

Comment: At our company we kept a copy of Eclipse with the same plugins installed, just to make sure that everything compiles. Same with the JDK and default set of libraries. These were copied over to each computer to keep the development in sync. Of course if you are just two developers it should be easy to keep everything in sync by just telling the other dev what you are using. Maven can be used to share artifacts (e.g. .jar files for the API) and such, and Maven will auto-magically keep things in sync and copy it to a local folder. But it takes some time to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But you will need to change its configurations to not lock the workspace. This is the default behaviour.

This is the option:

```
-Dosgi.locking="none"
```

Use it in your vmargs or in ini file. I do not need to mention you and your friend need some discipline to not be caught by side effects of this solution.

For example, if both are working in file A, when the first save eclipse will ask if you wish update with system file changes. If you click yes your changes will be lost.

Comment: Please indicate how you can change the default behavior, Jose.

Comment: didn't know that you can switch workspace locking off. Where do you do it?

Comment: +1 But what are the side effects? Using the same workspace on two computers seems like a rather crazy idea to me, I don't believe that Eclipse was build for that kind of behavior...

Comment: You mean adding it to eclipse.ini? Unfortunately, when I do that, Eclipse cannot open the workspace because I have to set locking to java.io with "-Dosgi.locking=java.io" for that to work on the AFP server.

Comment: Your afp server is mac or Linux? I used this solution on ubuntu 10 serving afp to my macox(Mountain Lion). Did you consider using version control instead?

Comment: @JoseAreas The server and clients are all Mac OS X. One client is Mountain Lion, the other Snow Leopard. Server is Snow Leopard.